# xdg-screensaver lock returns exit code 4 even though it worked

Tags: kde, opensuse, screen-lock, xdg

On an up to date openSUSE Tumbleweed install with KDE, running `xdg-screensaver lock` works (as in, the screen is locked just as if I'd done so through the UI), but it returns exit code 4, which according to the man page means "The action failed.". What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a little bug inside the shell script used for `xdg-screensaver`. I also have `openSUSE Tumbleweed` and I've tested it and got the same exit code. Probably we have the same versions and therefore the bug and solution to this problem will be work for both.

The `xdg-screensaver` is under `/usr/bin` directory and you should open/edit it by using:

```bash
sudo -e /usr/bin/xdg-screensaver

#In zsh you can use:
sudo -e =xdg-screensaver
```

---

To debug the problem:

Around the line `593` you will see this section:

```bash
case "$DE" in
  kde)
    if [ -n "${KDE_SESSION_VERSION}" ]; then
      screensaver_freedesktop "$1"
    else
      screensaver_kde3 "$1"
    fi
    ;;
```

In my case (maybe same for you) the line to execute is `screensaver_freedesktop "$1"` so you can now go that function which is around line `741`. In that section you can see this code:

```bash
case "$1" in
    suspend)
    dbus-send --session \
              --dest=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver \
              --type=method_call \
              --print-reply \
              --reply-timeout=2000 \
              /ScreenSaver \
              org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.Inhibit \
              string:$window_id \
              string:xdg-screensaver \
              | grep uint32 | cut -d ' ' -f 5 >| "$screensaver_file.cookie" \
              2> /dev/null
    result=$?
    ;;
                                                                              
    #... more code ...
                                                                              
    lock)
    dbus-send --session \
              --dest=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver \
              --type=method_call \
              /ScreenSaver \
              org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.Lock \
              2> /dev/null
    ;;
```

Note that all the case statements such as `suspend` have at the end the line: `result=$?` but in the case statement `lock` this is not present. Maybe developers forgot to add that line. So the solution here is adding that line:

```bash
 lock)
    dbus-send --session \
              --dest=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver \
              --type=method_call \
              /ScreenSaver \
              org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.Lock \
              2> /dev/null
    result=$?
    ;;
```

Btw, if you run the command:

```bash
dbus-send --session \
              --dest=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver \
              --type=method_call \
              /ScreenSaver \
              org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.Lock \
              2> /dev/null
```

and you after print the exit code with: `echo $?` you will get `0` status code. So that means the actually all runs perfectly but the script missed the line `result=$?`.

The `result` variable is used for the exit status. You can see in the last lines of the file:

```bash
if [ $result -eq 0 ]; then
    exit_success
else
    exit_failure_operation_failed
fi
```

And what the function `exit_failure_operation_failed` does:

```bash
exit_failure_operation_failed()
{
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "xdg-screensaver: $@" >&2
    fi

    exit 4
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you want to submit the relevant patch? If not, I am happy to do so.

Comment: @MarkRaymond if you want to do it, no problem! Go ahead! I really was not sure where is the correct site. I suppose is [this (GitLab)](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/). However there is the same `xdg-utils` project on Github. So I was not sure where it should be submitted the patch. If you know and want to submit it I will happy if you do so.

Comment: It appears it might be unmaintained. I'll email the xdg mailing list.

Comment: @MarkRaymond The GitHub seems to be more updated than GitLab, I don't know what should be the difference between both. Anyways, as you said, it's useful to mail them, hope you receive a response.